# the c++ programming language and school

Tags: c++

I am currently in university and despite how hard he tries our c++ teacher is horrible. I am thinking of picking up the c++ programming language 4th edition. I was curious since you are all great at this already is that a good first choice? I know some of the basics not nothing OOP related really. also my second question is they are making us learn java and c++ at the same time. I worry that that is not a good idea so I was curious what some of you thought.

Comment: Reading books is always a good idea (unless it's schildt or something)

Comment: You just need to compartmentalize with `Java` and `C++`. They are very different languages in how they are used despite a similar syntax. I would not recommend TCPPPL 4th Ed as a beginner's book particularly, see @CaptainObvlious 's posted link for good books. Eventually TCPPPL is a "must read" though imho.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I seen the list. I just wanted input from people who actually read/studied it to tell me if it is a right choice to start with. thank you for your post though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after a book that goes C++ in depth, the book you mentioned is a great start. Though if you are a beginner it may not be the easiest thing to work through.

I would also recommend the C++ tutorials found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

They will teach you all the basics of C++, and will help to supplement the stuff you are reading in "C++ Programming Language 4th Edition".

As the for the having to learn C++ and Java at the same time, I personally do not think it is a good idea (though others may disagree). Learning C++ can be a challenging process on its own, let alone throwing another language into the mix.

Comment: Challenging, but highly rewarding =)

Comment: See I thought it was a bad idea as well. I do not understand why they are doing it. My school is horrible so I am trying to learn myself the best way I can.

Comment: Fair enough :-) Try not to let stress you out too much though. There is a ton of really good learning resources out there. And with a little bit of dedication, you should easily be able to get ahead of the rest of the class (and maybe even teach the teacher a thing or two).

Comment: Thing is, not all jobs out there are in C++ so getting somewhat familiar with two big players might help more students get a job than only teaching one or the other.

Comment: I completely agree with that, though teaching students several languages at the same time may end up doing more harm than good. Teaching one and then the other, would be a much better approach.

Comment: its weird because here is the order, they are teaching us c++ which they are naming programming 1(horrible teacher) and they are teaching us java 1 at the same time. next term i get programming 2(more c++) and mobile development. it is like there trying to confuse us lol @Sir.Tiddlesworth would you suggest c++ primer 5th edition as A good first book? I know the basics some what I just am missing a few things here and there. But I would like to get really good at c++ but need excersizes to be able to do it as hands on for me is the best way I learn..thanx for your help again

Comment: @Geekstatused While I haven't read C++ Primer myself, I have heard a lot of good stuff about it. I think it would definately be worth checking out.

Comment: @Sir.Tiddlesworth Thank you very much for all of your help I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem. All the best with your studies.